# query to return additional column with some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

table      : Emaployee
Columns: name(nvarchar(256)), Salary(decimal(18,2))

Now, I want result with additional column 
'Grade'= 
    'A' if salary<15000.00, 
    'B' if 25000.00>Salary>15000.00, 
    'C' if salary>25000.00

How can I write a Query for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       salary, 
       (CASE 
             WHEN salary<15000 THEN 'A' 
             WHEN salary>15000 AND salary <25000 THEN 'B' 
             ELSE 'C' 
       END) AS grade
FROM employee
```

Haven't tried the following but it may work too:

```
SELECT name, 
       salary, 
       IIF (salary<15000, 'A', IIF (salary>15000 AND salary<25000, 'B', IIF (salary>25000, 'C', ))) AS grade
FROM employee
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing with 'IF' instead of 'CASE'?

Comment: I have added `IF` query to my answer but I dont know if it will work. Usually `CASE` is preferred over `IF`

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '<'.., for first IIF, I am using MS SQL server 2005

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make the query work using `IF` or `IIF`.

Answer (score 2):

IIF is introduced to T-SQL with Denali, so the latest can only work with Denali versions
Please check this [T-SQL IIF function tutorial](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-iif-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> 'Grade'= 
>       'A' if salary<15000.00, 
>       'B' if 25000.00>Salary>15000.00, 
>       'C' if salary>25000.00

The spec appears to be  flawed. You need to go back to your designer and ask them which grade applies to employees with salaries of exactly 15000.00 and 25000.00 receptively because these aren't specified. Below is a guess (and I don't recommend guessing in practice):

```
SELECT name, salary, 'A' AS Grade
  FROM Employee
 WHERE Salary BETWEEN 0 AND 14999.99
UNION
SELECT name, salary, 'B' AS Grade
  FROM Employee
 WHERE Salary BETWEEN 15000.00 AND 24999.99
UNION
SELECT name, salary, 'C' AS Grade
  FROM Employee
 WHERE Salary >= 25000.00;
```

Comment: exact result is not important for me, but the way to do it.. spec can be resolved later.. :)  +1 for a different approach..